# Error when Passing matrices from MATLAB to FORTRAN dll

Tags: matlab, dll, fortran

I have a simple intel fortran dll compiled from below:

```
function  add1(A,n)
!Expose  function  add1  to  users  of  this  DLL
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES  C,DLLEXPORT:: add1
implicit none
double  precision  A(n,n),add1(n,n)
integer n
call add2(A,n)
A=A+1.0
add1=A
end  function  add1

subroutine add2(a,n)
double precision a(n,n)
integer n
a=a+1
endsubroutine
```

I also have a header file for the dll:

```
double* add1(double*,int);
```

I use MATLAB to load the dll:

```
library='trydll.dll';
header='add1.h';
loadlibrary(library, header);
n=3;
haha=ones(n,n);
A=calllib('trydll','add1',haha,n)
unloadlibrary('trydll')
```

The sent matrix and the integer to the dll are severely wrong, and seem to be random numbers in the memory. Anyone has any idea where the mistake is?

Comment: from your Fortran code, it seems A isn't at all a matrix, guessing from the `n`, probably you need to declare `A` as `double  precision  A(n,n)` in `add1` and `add2`.

Comment: Sorry that I copied the wrong code, I changed. Ut was declared as a matrix and the error remains.

Comment: what is your output?  From what you write, you are returning a matrix where you have added 1 twice?

Comment: Try adding `!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: A` since `A` is passed by reference. The `C` style arguments makes them all by-val.

Comment: Wouldn't iso_c_binding easier and more portable here? I do not have Matlab and don't know its details, but I used it successfully to interface a Fortran DLL and a game in C++ on Windows and it was very straightforward and no directives were necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Like Barron suggested, use a subroutine to make life easier. Let MATLAB allocate the memory.

Here's a full working example using Intel Fortran 12.1:

```
subroutine CopyArray(A, B, n)

    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: CopyArray
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS: 'CopyArray' :: CopyArray
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: A, B
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES VALUE :: n

    real(8), intent(in),  dimension(n,n) :: A(n,n)
    real(8), intent(out), dimension(n,n) :: B(n,n)
    integer, intent(in) :: n

    B = A

end subroutine
```

Header file:

```
void CopyArray(double*, double*, int);
```

MATLAB script:

```
n = 3;
A = rand(n, n);
B = zeros(n, n);

[A2, B2] = calllib(libname, 'CopyArray', A, B, n);
```

Using the libpointer appears to be optional here. It appears that MATLAB automatically converts the array arguments to pointers. Also, note that the arguments that are passed by reference (A, B) are translated to function return values in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not currently able to code up your example for thorough testing, but I can say from experience that I've never had much luck calling Fortran libraries from Matlab the way you've shown. Here's what I do:

Use subroutines instead of functions. So, convert add1 to be more like:

```
SUBROUTINE add1(n,Ain,Aout)
  INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: n
  REAL*8, INTENT(in) :: Ain(n,n)
  REAL*8, INTENT(out) :: Aout(n,n)
  Aout = Ain + 1d0
END SUBROUTINE
```

Then call from Matlab with something like:

```
n = 3;
Ain = ones(n,n);
Aout = libpointer('doublePtr',zeros(1,n));
calllib('trydll','add1',n,Ain,Aout);
Aout = Aout.value;
```

It's possible that it's only that last `.value` part that you really need, but I'm running off of memory here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is a initialization problem. You can try the following script in MATLAB:

```
library='trydll.dll';
header='add1.h';
loadlibrary(library, header);
n=3;
arg_1 = libpointer('doublePtr',double(ones(1,n)))
arg_2 = libpointer('int32',n)
out_raw = libpointer('doublePtr') 
[output, arg_1] = calllib('trydll','add1',arg_1, arg_2)
unloadlibrary('trydll')
```

To see the FORTRAN/DLL output:

```
out = get(out_raw,'Value')
for i=1:n
    display(out[i]);
end
```